# prevent parsing of data to dates in microsoft excel home office 365

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am opening xslx files, and excel is parsing raw data like 1-35 into a date like "Jan-35". When clicking the cell to see the raw value, it is now an actual date and the real value is gone.

This has happened to me with two files. One was a webpage saved as xls; it parsed the cell values so I couldn't change them with Cell Format. I checked the cell values by reading the raw text and they were not dates but 1-35. The actual data in the text file was 1-35. If I change the Cell Format to General/Text, it turns to a number like 42123.

The other file is an xlsx, and I don't know how to read the raw text, because it's encoded like "��i��k���¿�l"g�xٲK�[�"

My question is how can I open a file without excel parsing data as dates? Once the file is opened, I cannot use Cell Format (General/Text) to retrieve the date.

Comment: What are your system settings?

Answer (score 0):

Try to import your data through the free Microsoft add-In [Power Query](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Introduction-to-Microsoft-Power-Query-for-Excel-6e92e2f4-2079-4e1f-bad5-89f6269cd605) (from Excel 2010). You can define the data types in the UI, before importing the datas into an Excel table. So you can so perhaps prevent to parse your column to date.

- From the Power Query ribbon [import data from a file](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Connect-to-an-Excel-or-CSV-file-Power-Query-fc377b2e-a742-4dea-8d7c-8e0f18c8e765?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)
- In the column context menu, [change the data type](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Guide-to-Power-Query-Context-Menus-20bbbad7-9536-490a-b799-561c6ff5560b?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#__toc371605432) to text
- Import your data into a table

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a legitimate answer. I solved my problem by using File > Export > CSV.

Even if I opened the CSV file, clicked on a date, the value box that shows formulas even showed a date; however, when I read the file with notepad the values were actually not dates.

I also tried importing the data from MS access, and MS access even showed dates.

I only needed a readable file for PHP, so my problem was resolved as the xlsx wasn't readable, but the CSV is not encoded.